# How Can I Connect Alchemy as a Custom RPC Node Provider in MetaMask?

Tags: metamask, rpc, alchemy

I saw this [doc](https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360043227612-How-to-add-a-custom-network-RPC) on adding a custom RPC endpoint to MetaMask. I'm wondering what are the steps to fill out the information specifically if I have an Alchemy endpoint available?

I would like to use the Polygon mainnet endpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First, you'll need to sign up for an [Alchemy](https://www.alchemy.com/) endpoint, and hit "create app".

[image: createapp]

2. Set it up as a polygon network. Once up, you can click on the app and hit "view key" to see the HTTP endpoint.

[image: viewapp]

And copy the HTTP endpoint.

3. Click on the Account button in your metamask:

[image: metamask]

4. Go to settings -> Networks -> Add Network

[image: settings]

[image: Networks]

[image: add network]

5. Fill in the details for polygon, replacing ALCHEMY_URL with the URL you copied from Alchemy

Network Name: Polygon Mainnet
Network URL: ALCHEMY_URL
Chain ID: 137
Currency Symbol: MATIC
Block Explorer (Optional): https://polygonscan.com

Hit save.

Then you should see it in the `networks` dropdown of your metamask!